# Change UINavigationController style on the fly - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 UIViewControllers: A and B. B is Detailed view of A. In A view, my UINavigationViewController has Default style. I want to change style of navigationController to BlackOpaque, when I push B viewController. How to do this? In B `viewDidLoad` method, i tried to do this:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are changing the style of the toolbar, not the style of the navigation bar. This should do it:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```